# How can I batch rename filenames in the console

Tags: find, rename

I have a great number of files whose name is "img800400_497708.307247.png", and I would like to change all dots (periods) to an underscore using the console. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this fairly easily with the `rename` command. The only problem is preserving the extension. We start by replacing all the dots, but then replace `_png` with `.png`. You'll obviously need to adapt that for other extension types.

```
cd /path/to/images
rename 's/\./_/g; s/_png$/.png/' *.png -vn
```

Note: the `-vn` on the end will only demonstrate what it would do. It's a safety trigger. Check the command does what you want and then remove that last part.

A super-simple test harness:

```
$ touch file.{01..10}.png
$ rename 's/\./_/g; s/_png$/.png/' *.png -vn
file.01.png renamed as file_01.png
file.02.png renamed as file_02.png
file.03.png renamed as file_03.png
file.04.png renamed as file_04.png
file.05.png renamed as file_05.png
file.06.png renamed as file_06.png
file.07.png renamed as file_07.png
file.08.png renamed as file_08.png
file.09.png renamed as file_09.png
file.10.png renamed as file_10.png
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! but it doesn t work :(

Comment: Since the `rename` command is perl-based, how about using a *negative lookahead* to replace only those periods that are not followed by the extension? something like `rename -vn -- 's/[.](?!png$)/_/g'`

Comment: Why not simply remove the trailing *g* in the first command to only replace the first dot. **g** means global and replace all occurrence of pattern. Also options do not go at the end but after the command name and -vn does not exist but -v -n does. I mean use `rename -v -n 's/\./_/' *.png`

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution that removes the extension, replaces the periods with underscores, then adds back the extension:

```
for f in *.png; do g="${f%.*}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${g//./_}.png"; done
```

Remove the `echo` once you have satisfied yourself whether it works. It could fairly easily be extended to a general `.ext` extension if you have more than one file type, for example

```
for f in *.*; do g="${f%.*}"; e="${f##*.}"; echo mv -- "$f" "${g//./_}.$e"; done
```

Comment: That's unnecessary complex. Just use one `/` if you only want to replace the first `.`: `for f in *.png; do; echo mv -- "$f" "${f/./_}"; done`.

Comment: @DavidOngaro I *don't* want to only replace the first `.`, I want to replace *all except the last*

Comment: Ok, but from @user3601754's example it seems he doesn't need that? But only he can tell what he actually needs...